# Capturing the state of redux-form in JEST unit test cases

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

We are writing the unit test cases for our **`react-redux`** application where we are adding them with **`JEST`**. Here, we are not able to capture the state of **`redux-form`**. We have written the test cases for **`mapStateToProps`** but this is not getting captured in **`UI UT`** coverage. So 2 issues are here:

1. How do we achieve 100% coverage for the redux-form state?
2. How can we capture the state of redux form?